# Linear gradient as body background of first full-screen-view; after that solid bg color

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to have a gradient gradually turning from white into blue from top to bottom. If I open the page, the final blue tone should be reached at the lower edge of my screen. If I scroll down any further, the final blue tone should consistently stay as a solid background color. How can I achive this in the simplest way possible? Old browser support is not important.

This version isn't working because the gradient loops every screen-height:

```
background: linear-gradient(0deg, blue 51%, white 100%);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below:

```css
html {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(0deg, blue 51%, white) top/100% 100vh no-repeat
    blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:2000px"></div>
```